# How to replace input string in python

Tags: python, tkinter, file-upload

I use tkinter make interface to select folder directory and i get C:/Users/dtung/Desktop/ and i want to convert it to C:\Users\dtung\Desktop\ because i use autoit to select file. this is my code

```
import_file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
list = os.listdir(path=import_file_path)
import_file_path.replace("/","\\")
```

replace function does't work with any string or character(dont have any error it just does't work), when i print it out i just received old string.

Comment: because you don't assign the new string to any variable you could print. Why the `autoit` tag?

Comment: the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module has functions for detailing with file paths. You should consider using it instead of string replacement.

Comment: i use \\ to print  \ and i dont know cant use \\ for \.
`Autoit` because i need change "/"(can use by send_keys) in directory to "\"(use dialog window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem. The code above works fine for me.

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

import_file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
list = os.listdir(path=import_file_path)
print('Before', import_file_path)
import_file_path = import_file_path.replace("/", os.sep)
print(os.path.join(import_file_path))
print('After', import_file_path)
```

prints out this on my Windows machine

```
Before C:/Users/Mega/Documents/HuaweiMusic
C:\Users\Mega\Documents\HuaweiMusic
After C:\Users\Mega\Documents\HuaweiMusic
```

By the way, why do you need to mix Autoit and Python?

Comment: Thank you so much. i can't use send_keys() every time i use it just show dialog window(file .dwg).Could you tell me what doesn't mean of os.sep ?
`import_file_path = import_file_path.replace("/", os.sep)
    print("os",import_file_path)`

Comment: and out:`os C:\Users\dtung\Desktop`
So do we need this`os.path.join(import_file_path)`

Comment: No, you do not need both ways. the replace and the join command lead to the same result. The os.sep returns the seperator used by your operating system. On Windows \ and on Linux /.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to fix the problem:

```py
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

import_file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
list = os.listdir(path=import_file_path)
import_file_path = import_file_path.replace("/", "\\")
```

Comment: the problem is replace. I already imported those 2 libraries.